# WorkBench no usa nombre de mi modelo al crear el script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola a todos tengo una duda y es que cada vez que hago un modelo con el WorkBrench al exportar el modelo a script nunca coge el nombre de modelo si no el de la bbdd 'mydb'. Osea por ejemplo si creo un modelo llamado `bbdd` y lo exporto al script WorkBench me lo crea así:

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`usuario` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`usuario` (
  `idusuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Luego me toca ir cambiando 'mydb' por el nombre del modelo en este caso era bbdd.
¿Se puede cambiar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes ir a tu conexion y seleccionar tu base de datos como la definida por defecto.
te esta tomando la que genera automaticamente el workbench.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias @Ernesto RIncon